# Find all File to log and add string to log BASH

Tags: logging, find, mkdir

Find all the files in the folder, create list(log) and the log at the beginning of each Append To row "mkdir -p /VOLUME1/path

Like This:

```
/volume1/TEST/folder1/1.jpg
/Volume1/TEST/folder2/2.jpg
```

I Try this:
1#cd directory:

```
cd /volume1/TEST
```

2#make LOG

```
ls **/* >/volume1/log.txt
```

3#add new path (String)

```
sed -e 's/^/mkdir -p /VOLUME1/TEST2/' /volume1/log.txt >/volume1/log2.txt
```

I Need this :add on every line :

```
mkdir -p /Volume1/TEST2/folder1/1.jpg
mkdir -p /Volume1/TEST2/folder2/2.jpg
.
.
```

but my output is `"/Volume1/TEST2/ folder1/1.jpg"`  ( I miss `"mkdir -p/Volume1/"` and  gap is moreover

(LINUX)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes. At least, it did work for me:

```
sed -e 's/^/mkdir -p \/VOLUME1\/TEST2\//' log.txt > log2.txt
```

The beginning of the result:

```
mkdir -p /VOLUME1/TEST2/confEclipse/MIT-Eclipse-CheckStyle-20160408.xml
mkdir -p /VOLUME1/TEST2/confEclipse/MIT-Eclipse-CodeStyle-CleanUp-20160408.xml
mkdir -p /VOLUME1/TEST2/confEclipse/MIT-Eclipse-CodeStyle-CodeTemplates-20160408
```

Comment: Now it works well , but I found that in the filenames can not be gaps , such as TEST NAME , you would not know how to do it now? (
TEST file was only examples)

Comment: I do not get gaps within the lines in my test. Do the filenames already contain gaps?
You may have to escape the spaces before adding the `mkdir ...` part

Comment: Any news on the gaps?